# multiple list outputs created by a function, how do i put this to a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have the following function

```
macd, macdsignal, macdhist = talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
```

I want to make those new values part of my existing dataframe,  how can I do that?
This is what I tried

```
 df['macd'], df['macdsignal'], df['macdhist'] = talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
```

Edit to add a before and after

Before

```
Close 
10
10 
10
```

After

```
Close    macd    macdsignal    macdhist
10       1.1     3.8           5.7
10       3.2     8.7           4.2   
10       1.9     9.5           1.2
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your variables? Desired output would be good as well.

Comment: How is `df[['macd', 'macdsignal', 'macdhist']] = pd.DataFrame(talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9))`?

Comment: @Abdou ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: @OptimusPrime Try `df[['macd', 'macdsignal', 'macdhist']] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip(*talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)))`.

Comment: @OptimusPrime please consider accepting the provided answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)` returns a list of lists, you can get the following two things:

#### Assign the columns to the same dataframe:

```
lofl = talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
df[['macd', 'macdsignal', 'macdhist']] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip(*lofl))
```

#### Create a new dataframe with `df.assign`:

```
lofl = talib.MACD(df.Close.values, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
new_cols = ['macd', 'macdsignal', 'macdhist']
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(new_cols, lofl)}
df = df.assign(**d)
```

I hope this proves useful.